# How to get machine name from ip address in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to get the machine name from IP address in SQL Server, is there anything that I could do to accomplish my task

Comment: OP originally wanted to find the machine address or name from an IP that logged into the Instance.

Answer (score 2):

**DB:**

```
IPAdd | MachineName
```

**Query:**

```
select MachineName from DBTable where IPAdd='yourIPAddress'
```

**Try with:**

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('MachineName')
```

**Or**

```
SELECT  
   CONNECTIONPROPERTY('net_transport') AS net_transport,
   CONNECTIONPROPERTY('protocol_type') AS protocol_type,
   CONNECTIONPROPERTY('auth_scheme') AS auth_scheme,
   CONNECTIONPROPERTY('local_net_address') AS local_net_address,
   CONNECTIONPROPERTY('local_tcp_port') AS local_tcp_port,
   CONNECTIONPROPERTY('client_net_address') AS client_net_address
```

**Or**

```
SELECT @@SERVERNAME;
```

**Refer:**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187944.aspx

Hope its helpful.

Comment: actually this is not my case, I have dynamic IPs, I have to get the ip dynamically.

Comment: then you will have to mention programming language you are using.

Comment: I have an IP address and I need to get the machine name from that IP address in MSSQL

Comment: machine names are stored in DB?

Comment: then what is problem with above query?? can you share[Paste] DB structure?

Comment: friend I have some machine names in a table like:

Machine Name
machine1
Machine2
Machine3

Now all I want to do is that I have to get the IP address of a user which is a dynamic IP and then I have to get machine name against that IP, if the machine name is from the above mentioned table then I have to perform some operations.

Comment: I have only machine names in my db table, I need to parse IP into computer name in sql, is there any way to get this??

Answer (score 2):

I might be wrong but as far as I know, SQL Server can not do what you want. Resolving machine names from IP address is something your network's DNS server does.

Best idea I come up with to get that info from SQL Server is using `xp_cmdshell` command to execute command prompt commands from SQL.

```
xp_cmdshell 'NBTSTAT -A 10.10.10.10'
```

However, please note that xp_cmdshell needs to be enabled on your server first in order to work, and often it is not beacause of possible security issues. Read more about xp_cmdshell at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175046.aspx

Also, result from this will be just like from command prompt and it will require some parsing to get exact machine name from it. Check this topic for more info: [Get Results from XP_CMDSHELL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9501192/get-results-from-xp-cmdshell)

I don't know your solution architecture and how you get the IP address, but if it is from some client side applications, it might be easier to find client's machine name executing `SELECT HOST_NAME()` from client's side query or with .NET and sending machine names directly.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is called a [Reverse DNS lookup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_DNS_lookup). There are command line tools that can do it ([nslookup.exe](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/200525)) or you can use the [`DnsQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682016%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API. You have no business doing either from T-SQL so don't try to do it. Resolve the IP to name in the client.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this natively in the SQL language, your best bet is to either:

1/ shell out via xp-cmdshell and run nslookup, which will require some string manipulation to get the command right and then some cleaning up of the output to return the machine name

2/ Write a C# CLR function that takes the IP address as an input and makes use of the Dns.GetHostEntry method to resolve and return the name.

See here for the documentation:

[Dns.GetHostEntry Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.dns.gethostentry.aspx)

I wrote a really quick simple CLR function for getting the machine name from the IP Address is below, please note there is no error handling or input checking to make sure the IP is valid before trying to resolve it, and it won't give you the IP address if you pass it a hostname, but it can be easily modified to include all these things, it's just to give you an idea of how it could work:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;
using System.Net;

public partial class UserDefinedFunctions
{
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction]
    public static SqlString dnsResolve(String ipAddress)
    {
        IPHostEntry host = Dns.GetHostEntry(ipAddress);
        return new SqlString(host.HostName.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to get the name of your machine.

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY(N'MachineName');
```

May be above can serve your purpose.

Comment: sorry but this is not what I am looking for, I simply want to resolve an IP address in machine name

Answer (score 0):

```
--Im using command line for checking host name after IP
declare @IP as varchar(15)
declare @cmd as varchar(1000) 
set @IP='192.168.0.1' 
SET @cmd = 'ping -a -n 1 ' + @IP 
Create Table #Output (Output varchar(150) default(''))
INSERT INTO #Output 
EXEC xp_cmdshell @cmd 
Begin try 
Select top 1 Replace(LEFT([Output],CHARINDEX('[', [output])-2),'Pinging ','') as HostName from #Output where Output is not null 
End Try 
Begin catch 
Select 'Host name for:' + @IP +' could not be find'
End catch 
drop table #Output
```

Answer (score 0):

This actually works: Modified answer from Sky Diver

```
--Im using command line for checking host name after IP
    declare @IP as varchar(15)
    declare @cmd as varchar(1000) 
    set @IP='137.201.17.204' 
    SET @cmd = 'ping -a -n 1 ' + @IP 
    Create Table #Output (Output varchar(150) default(''))
    INSERT INTO #Output 
    EXEC xp_cmdshell @cmd 
    Begin try 
    Select top 1 Replace(LEFT([Output],CHARINDEX('[', [Output])-2),'Pinging ','') as HostName from #Output where Output like 'Pinging%'
    End Try 
    Begin catch 
    Select 'Host name for:' + @IP +' could not be find'
    End catch 
    --drop table #Output
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  When posting code, please make sure you format it.  See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Answer (score 0):

Try this you will get a system Name.......

select HOST_NAME()

regards : Rajsri Vyshnnavi