# Monitor BCP progress

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, bcp

Heyo folks,
Just looked on Google and around on this site, and there's very little information.
Given a query which is `"SELECT * FROM Table WHERE (various)"`, I'm putting in a BCP utility query like thus, called from C# (.net 3.5, but can be raised).

```
xp_cmdshell 'bcp "SELECT * FROM [DB].dbo.[table]  " queryout "\\networkpath\bla\file.csv" -N -S localhost -T -E -m0'
```

However, when I run this query in SQL Management Studio, it helpfully keeps supplying me with "1000 rows were copied." messages. I want to get those messages in my C# application.

I've tried several C# methods, including SqlDependency, SqlConnection.InfoMessage, BeginExecuteNonQuery(), etc; hence the lack of C# code.

What would be the best method to do this?

Cheers

Comment: Perhaps SSMS is querying out 1000 rows at a time and reporting based on that. You could do the same.

Answer (score 0):

BCP is a command line application being executed on the server via xp_cmdshell; so the bcp is writing to stdout on the server, capturing that output is discussed here [Get Results from XP_CMDSHELL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9501192/get-results-from-xp-cmdshell) ; this might give you what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I understand the question that way that you want to run this `bcp.exe` command and monitor its progress. Run it using `Process.Start` and [redirect console output to your application](https://www.google.com/webhp?complete=1&hl=en#complete=1&hl=en&q=process.start%20redirect%20output). Then, you can parse it.

If you run it using `xp_cmdshell` the `InfoMessage` event will receive the messages (or they might be output as rows, now sure right now).